# Parsing XML to Database Table Using PLSQL

Tags: xml, plsql

can anyone advise how to parse the following XML to the desired database table using plsql? Thank you.

```
<Label name=“Case”>C12</Label>
<Label name=“Route”>
    <String name=“PName”>UE21010</String>
    <Integer name=“Operation”>12345</Integer>
    <Label name=“Process”>
        <String name=“PNumber”>W98765</String>
        <String name=“Recipe”>Burn101</String>
    </Label>
</Label>
<Label name=“User”>
    <String name=“EmpNo”>E1234</String>
    <String name=“Name”>John</String>
</Label>
```

Desired Output in Database Table:

```
+-----------------------+---------+
| Item                  | Value   |
+-----------------------+---------+
| Case                  | C12     |
+-----------------------+---------+
| Route.PName           | UE21010 |
+-----------------------+---------+
| Route.Operation       | 12345   |
+-----------------------+---------+
| Route.Process.PNumber | W98765  |
+-----------------------+---------+
| Route.Process.Recipe  | Burn101 |
+-----------------------+---------+
| User.EmpNo            | E1234   |
+-----------------------+---------+
| User.Name             | John    |
+-----------------------+---------+
```

Comment: Please see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952). Kindly do not post images of code or table structures.

Comment: Hi, sorry I am new here and don't know how to display the output table and thought using image would be the best of my knowledge here. Key objective is just trying to get my question clearly here.

Comment: If you read the link I gave you, you will notice there's an "ASCII data table generator tool". This can help you provide a table that you can use here.

Comment: Thanks @Scratte, I had amended my enquiry.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something along the lines of this:

```
DECLARE
v_xml xmltype;
BEGIN
SELECT XMLTYPE('...xml here...') INTO v_xml FROM DUAL;

INSERT INTO table (Case,Route.PName,...) VALUES
SELECT EXTRACT(v_xml, '//Label[@name='Case']'), EXTRACT(v_xml, '//Label[@name='Route']'),...
FROM DUAL
END;
```